# Apache2 decides to ignore the ErrorLog location. How to fix?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, log-files

My `apache2.conf` file contains the lines `ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error_log` and `CustomLog /var/www/logs/access_log common`. I only get server shutdown/restart notifications there, however. All other logs get sent to the original locations (`/var/log/apache2`). I wasted a day debugging in the blind until I worked that out. How do I get all my logs to get sent where I want them?

The (condensed) `apache2.conf` file looks similar to this (without the modules and directories):

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
AccessFileName .htaccess
DefaultType None
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error_log
LogLevel debug
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf
Include httpd.conf
Include ports.conf
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
CustomLog /var/www/logs/access_log common
Include conf.d/
Include sites-enabled/

ServerName 158.132.10.185
ServerRoot /var/www
DocumentRoot /var/www
AddType application/x-httpd-cgi .cgi

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by all other logs? You have probably defined a number of virtual hosts and these other logs belong to them. So, you should set log file locations on a per virtual host basis in corresponding `VirtualHost` configuration sections.

Comment: Actually, I haven't even got to virtual hosts yet. It's not a complicated setup. I meant "all other logging", rather than "all other logs". Sorry. Anyway, the logs in question are `error.log`, `access.log` and `other_vhosts_access.log`.

Comment: I suppose you are on Debian or Ubuntu, please check `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`, your default `VirtualHost` configuration is right there.

Comment: Ah, you're right. There's another `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` there. Is it better to modify that file, or do something in the `apache2.conf` file to make it use my settings?

Comment: Well since settings are per virtual host it's better to modify that file I think.